# Converting a number to binary

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I am working on a method to generate an import file to work with a third party application.  The file is part plain text and part binary. Someone created a [document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B48BXDxt74TQeDJEQjdlZTdRME9WZUJLY1dVcU45UQ/view) that gives a high level method of converting a time to binary.  I admit, bitwise operations have always been over my head.  Below is my function to generate the binary part of the file, but I don't know if this is correct.

```
private function formatTime($time1) {
  //$time should be float
  $time = floatval($time1);
  $time = $time + 2;
  //Process byte 4 (which is the exponent)

  //Mask out everything else
  $byte4 = $time & bindec('01111111100000000000000000000000');

  //Move to first 8 bits
  $byte4 >>= 23;

  //Multiple by 2
  $byte4 <<= 1;
  //$byte4 should be correct at this stage (but double check)

  //Process byte 3 (this includes add "0" to bit 8)
  $byte3 = $time & bindec('00000000011111110000000000000000');
  $byte3 >>= 16;

  //Process byte 2
  $byte2 = $time & bindec('00000000000000001111111100000000');
  $byte2 >>= 8;

  //Process byte 1
  $byte1 = $time & bindec('00000000000000000000000011111111');

  //Put them together in correct order
  $hytek = 0;

  $hytek = $byte4 | ($byte3 << 8) | ($byte2 << 16) | ($byte1 << 24);

  return pack('f',$hytek);
}
```

The documentation I referenced says to add 2 to the exponent, so I added 2 to $time, but I don't know if that's correct.  I'm also guessing on packing the result.  What I'm curious about is if the bitwise parts appear correct.

When I tried importing the resulting file, the software recognized the sections of the file but found no times to use.

Comment: when you tested it, did it work? if yes then it is correct.

Comment: Haha...no it didn't work.

Comment: well you never actually said that in the question

Comment: I think the `$time = $time + 2;` is wrong: the doc says *"add 2 to the exponent"*, so do `$byte4 +=2;` just before `$byte4<<=1;`. The bitwise ops look okay. Btw, is this right: `$time` is a float, and are converting *to* a 'hytek float' (`$hytek`) - why are you then doing the `pack("f")`?

Comment: Thanks, Kenney, that makes more sense.  It still doesn't work but I think you're right :)